# Laravel mapping collections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a collection of data. My return data is like:

```
userId:2
movieId:2
rating:2

userId:2
movieId:3
rating:5
```

And I would like to get the data like this:

```
userId:2
movieId:{2,3}
rating:{2,5}
```

Can I do it by mapping?

```
$userX = Rating::where("userId", '=', $id)
        ->pluck('movieId')->toArray();
$data = Rating::where("userId", '!=', $id)
        ->whereIn('movieId', $userX)
        ->orderby('userId')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby) user.
If so you could do:

```
Rating::where("userId",'!=',$id)
        ->whereIn('movieId', $userX)
        ->groupBy('userId')
```

Comment: with gropby i just get the just one result by user i doesn't agroup the movieId and rating.

Comment: I know that. But don't you want to keep the relation between the movie and the rating? in other words, to know which rating the user gave to a given Movie?
Maybe you should update your question with more info. You need this data for what? for a view, chart,...?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. SQL doesn't give an array, so I have to transform the string into an array using `concat` and `group_concat`:

```
 DB::table('ratings')
        ->select('userId',
            DB::raw("CONCAT('[',group_concat(movieId),']') as movieId"),
            DB::raw("CONCAT('[',group_concat(rating),']') as rating")
        )
```